# Issue with User Photo (Profile Picture) with parse

Tags: ios, image, photo, parse-platform

I have some issues with user photos (profile pictures). For every time a single user update his profile picture, it also updates the rest of the users with the same image. How do I change it so it doesn't change everywhere? I am using parse.com

I'm using following codes.

**Uploading the photo:**

```
- (void)uploadProfilePhoto {
NSData *imageData;
NSString *imageName;
NSString *imageType;

//Shrink it
//Upload profile photo

(self.image != nil); {
    UIImage *resizeImage = [self resizeImage:self.image toWidth:320.0f andHeight:320.0f];
    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizeImage);
    imageName = @"profileimage.png";
    imageType = @"image";
}

PFFile *image = [PFFile fileWithName:imageName data:imageData];
[image saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something went wrong!" message:@"Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else {
        PFObject *UserPhotos = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
        [UserPhotos setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
        [UserPhotos setObject:imageType forKey:@"imageType"];
        [UserPhotos setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"user"];
        [UserPhotos setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"uploaderId"];
        [UserPhotos setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"uploaderUsername"];
        [UserPhotos saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something went wrong!" message:@"Please try uploading your photo again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];
            }
            else {
                //Everything was successfull!

            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

}

**When I retrieve the photo:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
[query includeKey:@"user"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!object) {
        return NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    PFFile *imageFile = object[@"image"];

    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!data) {
            return NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        // Do something with the image
        self.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }];
}];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

}

Thanks!